# How do I use Perl IPC::Run3 to read stdout and stderr from a subprocess?

Tags: perl, pipe

I want to run a `make` command from a Perl script so I can capture its stdout and stderr streams.  I know I could use `open(MAKE, "make 2>&1 |")` but this gives problems building the right shell command to pass arguments to `make`, and using `open(MAKE, "-|", @makecmd, "2>&1")` doesn't work because passing the command as an array doesn't spawn a subshell to do the redirection.

I came across [IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3) and I've got it working, but my use of filehandles is ugly - basically I've had to spawn a `cat` subprocess to get a handle that I can tell `IPC::Run3` to write to so my script can read from it, and my attempts at passing `STDIN` for this purpose have failed.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run3;

#my $pipe = \*STDIN;           #-- this produces no output and hangs
#open(my $pipe, "<&STDIN");    #-- this outputs "foo bar" and hangs
open(my $pipe, "|cat");        #-- this works, but extra process is ugly

run3 "echo foo; echo bar >&2", \undef, $pipe, $pipe;

while (<$pipe>) {
    print ">>> $_";
}
```

Comment: Does your Makefile take user input?

Answer (score 6):

You don't. You use IPC::Run instead. Naïve use of IPC::Open3 leaves you open to deadlocks. Avoiding this involves using IO::Select or some other mechanism. The work involved is extensive. IPC::Open3 is just too low-level for practical use.

---

That said, you're only dealing with one file handle. *That* can be done relatively simply using `open3`.

```perl
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );

open(local *CHILD_STDIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
*CHILD_STDIN if 0;
pipe(local (*READER, *WRITER)) or die $!;
my $pid = open3('<&CHILD_STDIN', '>&WRITER', '>&WRITER', @cmd);

close(WRITER);

while (<READER>) {
   ...
}

waitpid($pid);
```

Yuck! It's much cleaner using IPC::Run.

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );

run \@cmd, \undef, '>pipe', \my $pipe, '2>&1';

while (<$pipe>) {
   ...
}

close($pipe);
```

Well, that's what the documentation says, but it doesn't work. You actually need

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );
use Symbol   qw( gensym );

run \@cmd, \undef, '>pipe', (my $pipe = gensym), '2>&1';

while (<$pipe>) {
   ...
}

close($pipe);
```

And if you want all the output, you could simply use

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );

run \@cmd, \undef, \my $output;
```

---

Finally, you mention problems building shell commands.

What you were looking for is

```perl
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote(@cmd) . ' 2>&1';
open(my $pipe, '-|', $cmd);

while (<$pipe>) {
   ...
}

close($pipe);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  This seems to do what I want most cleanly...

    use IPC::Run qw(run);

    run ["sh", "-c", "echo foo; echo bar >&2"], \undef, '>pipe', \*PIPE, '2>&1';

    while (<PIPE>) {
        print ">>> $_";
    }

Comment: yes, but then you're using a global var. At the very least use `local *PIPE` instead of `*PIPE`. Or you know, avoid global vars entirely like I showed you.

Comment: TBH I didn't really understand the `gensym` call but, yes, your code as written does work, just like you said it would.  For me, explicitly naming the filehandle symbol is a bit less magical and more in keeping with what I've seen and used before.  But I have added `local` in to my own answer.

Comment: Re "*explicitly naming the filehandle symbol*", `$pipe` is no less explicit than `*PIPE`

Comment: `(my $pipe = gensym)` is a bit magical for me - it doesn't look like the usual sort of idiom for a filehandle.  `\*PIPE` immediately screams FILEHANDLE to me.

Comment: @kbro But you do something equivalent every time you do `open(my $fh, ...)`!! That said, I would avoid using a pipe at all, using `\my $output` or `sub { ... }` instead anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233558/discussion-between-kbro-and-ikegami).

Comment: yes, declaring `sub do_stuff {...}` and passing `\&do_stuff` to the stdout and stderr params of `IPC::Run3::run` worked well, with the contents of my `while (<$pipe>) { do stuff; }`  as the body of the sub (and `$_ = shift;` at the start to set up the default variable).  This way, Run3 deals with reading from the output stream of the subprocess.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ikegami I settled on this...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run qw(run);       # CPAN or yum install perl-IPC-Run
use Symbol qw(gensym);

run ["sh", "-c", "echo foo; echo bar >&2"], \undef, '>pipe', (my $pipe = gensym), '2>&1';

while (<$pipe>) {
    print ">>> $_";
}
```

Or, if `gensym` is a bit under-the-hood for you...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run qw(run);       # CPAN or yum install perl-IPC-Run
use IO::Handle;

run ["sh", "-c", "echo foo; echo bar >&2"], \undef, '>pipe', (my $pipe = new IO::Handle), '2>&1';

while (<$pipe>) {
    print ">>> $_";
}
```

Comment: You took what I posted and made it worse :( You're now using a global var for no reason.

Comment: Yup, sorry!  I put the `gensym` back.  But perhaps `new IO::Pipe` describes the intent better?

Comment: IO::Pipe will create a pipe. Not what we want.

Comment: `new IO::Handle`?

Comment: That does `my $io = gensym; bless $io, $class;`. That should work.

Comment: Hurrah!  Something readable for the user that hides the implementation details :-)  Sold!

Answer (score 0):

[IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3) can be used if you create an [IO::Pipe](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Pipe) and pass the "writer" filehandle to it, but that involves forking your main process so I wouldn't recommend it, though it does answer my original question.  @ikegami's solution with [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) is much more elegant.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run3;              # CPAN or yum install perl-IPC-Run3
use IO::Pipe;

my $pipe = new IO::Pipe;

if(my $pid = fork()) {
    # Parent
    $pipe->reader();

    while (<$pipe>) {
        print ">>> $_";
    }
}
elsif (defined $pid) {
    # Child ($pid = 0)
    $pipe->writer();
    run3 "echo foo; echo bar >&2", \undef, $pipe, $pipe;
}
else {
    # fork() failed
    die "failed to fork - $!";
}
```